# Building a complete web app as a frontend developer

Tags: web, frontend, backend, project

I’m a frontend developer, I can build stuff with html/css/js/react/vue

I want to build a personal project and I have a UI/UX engineer friend by my side
The only problem is that it’s just the two of us, we don’t have a backend guy to do the server side logic and database stuff

The project is a quiz maker, not too complex at least at this initial phase

What would you suggest? (was eyeballing something like Firebase but I’m not sure)

Comment: For this because both you and your mate are Front-End developers I would say that you could pick up Node very easy as Node being JavaScript. But last resort if the learning will be too much will be firebase cause you do not have to do a lot but then leverage their api and handle all operations

Answer (score 3):

Firebase is a great idea and seems to be a good match for your project. Even small teams can work on big projects with the help of Firebase services.

**Some details on Firebase:**

> Firebase helps building apps fast, without managing the infrastructure. Firebase gives you functionality like analytics, databases, messaging and crash reporting so you can move quickly and focus on your users.
>
> Firebase is backed by Google and built on their infrastructure, trusted by top apps and scales automatically, for even the largest apps. The products work great individually but share data and insights, so they work even better together.
>
> Very important for small teams is the quality of documentation and resources on the topic. Firebase has really great docs, some great examples on their GitHub page and  many tutorials on YouTube. There is also a huge Firebase community that keeps creating content about the services and features of Googles Cloud Platform Service.

`Firebase Auth` is a great tool for managing user authentication very easily.

To manage your quiz data in a database you could use `Firebase Cloud Firestore` or `Firebase Realtime Database`. [Check this article on the differences and what's right for your purpose.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore?hl=en)

It could be useful to use `Firebase Cloud Functions` for server-side operations that you can't do on your client-side.

[Check out the docs to learn more about Firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs)

Answer (score -2):

There is no right answer to this thing really depends on preference. I would recommend Node js or Firebase with React for first projects. Firebase gives you a lot of built-in functions that will serve you safely. Nodejs is relatively easy to understand and very orderly with react
And there is a lot of tuorials about them for your purpose